# Paste YYYYMMDDHHMMSS timestamp anywhere (hotkey shortcut)

Tags: keyboard, clock, text-input, text-editor

YYYYMMDDHHMMSS or YmdHis in PHP is the timestamp format used by Wayback Machine URL and the %A_Now variable in AutoHotKey.

It looks like this: 20171223145921.

#### How can I paste the timestamp of the current time anywhere?

Is there anything like AutoHotKey that can do the job?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is anything like AutoHotKey in Android but it is possible to get the timestamp in that format for the current time on demand.

You'd need [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or any other app which can run a command.

Setup a task with these actions:

1. Code → Run Shell:

   - Command: `date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
   - Store Output In: `%date`
2. System → Set Clipboard → Text: `%date`
3. Now, exit the Tasker, go back to Home Screen, long press your home screen to add a widget and choose Task Shortcut → pick your newly created Task → assign an icon at the bottom. That's it.

Whenever you would press that icon on your home screen, the current date-time would be copied in your clipboard automatically in the supplied format. You just have to copy paste it wherever you want it. There can be other methods to run a Tasker task less disruptively, such as through quick settings, as mentioned here by [Grayox96](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/6pbnjj/quick_setting_tile/dko2vdn) on Reddit.